# Link module output with content type

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I am confused on how to output links from a content type into a list in HTML. Currently I have the following code.

```
<div class="lenders-block-content clearfix">
  <ul>          
    <?php print render($content['field_link']) ?>
  </ul>     
</div>
```

The output just adds the links back-to-back within an `<a>` tag.

Is there a way to render the links so its outputted within a `<li>` tag?

I am using multiple links. When adding a content type you can add up to ten links.

Comment: I think you miss an `<li>` tag try with `<ul> <li>      
<?php print render($content['field_link']) ?>
</li></ul> `

Comment: @berramou - Hi Thanks for your reply, but issue is it will print all the links within the <li> instead of it printing several <li> tags. So I have multiple links, instead of just one link.

Comment: Ok so it's multivalue field?

Comment: @berramou yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments you field is multivalue field so you should loop over it and render the item inside `<li>` tag something like the following:

```
<div class="lenders-block-content clearfix">
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ($content['field_link'] as $key => $link):?>
      <?php if (is_numeric($key)): ?>
        <li> <?php print render($link) ?></li>
      <?php endif;?>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot this has worked!.

Comment: you are welcome, i'm glad that help!